# Is there an easier way to allow AJAX loading of Wordpress shortcode?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Looking for a general answer to the question I have (if I may).

I already have a plugin that will display content through shortcodes and attributes.

I am trying to switch this over to make use of AJAX loading (in an effort to speed up page load times).

I would like to know if there is an easier way than completely re-writing all of the code within my shortcode function to use AJAX to load the original shortcode instead?

The only thing is, if possible, I would like to retain usage of the original shortcode (so no changes are needed on pages or anywhere the shortcode appears).

My initial thought is to make a copy of the existing function tied to the shortcode, and then put that in AJAX function, and then change the original shortcode function to call this new function using AJAX.

In theory, would this work and save me having to completely re-write the plugin?

This is the original shortcode function as it stands:

```
// Operator Feed Shortcode
function shortcode_function($atts) {
    
    if(is_admin()) {
        return;
    }
    
    ob_start();
    
    // Get shortcode attributes
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'style'             => '',
        'carousel-items'    => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'type'              => '',
        'category'          => '',
        'show-images'       => '',
        'category-name-1'   => '',
        'category-title-1'  => '',
        'category-limit-1'  => '',
        'category-name-2'   => '',
        'category-title-2'  => '',
        'category-limit-2'  => '',
        'category-name-3'   => '',
        'category-title-3'  => '',
        'category-limit-3'  => '',
        'show-description'  => '',
        'description-limit' => '',
        'show-offline'      => '',
        'show-webchat'      => '',
        'show-webcam'       => '',
        'show-more-url'     => '',
        'show-more-class'   => '',
        'show-more-label'   => ''
    ), $atts);
        
        // Include shortcode contents
        include plugin_dir_path(__file__).'inc/function.php';

    
    return ob_get_clean();
    
}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_function');
```

**Update to show current AJAX call**

```
// The initial display of the AJAX shortcode
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax($atts) {

    // Get shortcode attributes
    // At this point, $atts contains the shortcode attributes and I need to get this into the AJAX query function below

    // Output initial loading message
    return '<div class="inveroak-feed-container-ajax">Loading...</div>';

}
add_shortcode('operator-feed', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax');

// The AJAX query
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_enqueue() {

    // This is where I need to take the $atts variable from the above function and use it for atts in the AJAX call, but its not accessible

    // Add the AJAX inline script
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'jquery',
        '
        var inveroak_feed_update_operators = function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    atts: "", 
                    action: "inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery(".inveroak-feed-container-ajax").empty().append(data);
                    console.log("Operators updated");
                }
            });
        }
        inveroak_feed_update_operators();
        setInterval(inveroak_feed_update_operators, 30000);
        '
    );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_enqueue');

// The returned output of the AJAX shortcode
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents() {

    // Get the attributes from the posted AJAX call
    $atts = isset($_POST['atts']) ? $_POST['atts'] : null;

    // Echo the display feed function
    echo inveroak_feed_shortcode($_POST['atts']);
    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents');
```

Comment: you could write a short code that simply is a wrapper to the short code you want to lazy load that simply returns the html of your short code from an ajax call.

Comment: @JasperB That's what I've been trying to do. However, the issue I have now is the shortcode callback is not outputting when the AJAX success runs. the Ajax is working, but the contents are empty.

Comment: The problem I’m really having now, is I cannot take the shortcode attributes and pass them through the Ajax JS stuff (I’m sure because of the order of things). So I cannot now figure how a shortcode can possibly be used with Ajax… although I’ve seen other plugins do it. Really need some help with this now… starting to get me down!

Comment: @JasperB That would make sense by the way, but that would require me to change all of the shortcodes I already have on the page doesn't it? Unless I create a new shortcode for the actual call.

Comment: You would need to replace it in the pages where it is placed and you would require some custom code to trigger the lazy loading. store the do_shortcode in a variable and return it with a json response, then in the callback of your ajax call append the content to the correct container. As for replacing the short code it self you could go that way too, unregister it and then reregister it with your own wrapper around it. in that case you don't need to replace it in the pages.

Comment: Still can't manage to do this. I'm stuck at trying to pass the shortcode parameters into the data variable for the AJAX call, but at this point $_POST is completely empty. How do other plugin devs do this?

Comment: Can you add a example of the ajax call you are posting ?

Comment: I would add the entire AJAX code I'm using, but I would prefer it to be in a discussion. I will add it to my question.

Comment: In the question is perfect, I should have specified that in my question. I'll have a look and let you know if I have a solution

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going to update my question with some clearer code and some comments to help.

Comment: the way I would do this, and I have seen it done in other plugins is to store it in a data attribute inside the output of `inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236194/discussion-between-lee-and-jasper-b).

Answer (score 1):

```
// The initial display of the AJAX shortcode
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax($atts) {

    // Get shortcode attributes
    // At this point, $atts contains the shortcode attributes and I need to get this into the AJAX query function below

    // Output initial loading message
    return '<div class="inveroak-feed-container-ajax" data-settings=\''.json_encode($atts).'\'>Loading...</div>';

}
add_shortcode('operator-feed', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax');

// The AJAX query
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    // This is where I need to take the $atts variable from the above function and use it for atts in the AJAX call, but its not accessible
    
    // Add the AJAX inline script
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'jquery',
        '
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".inveroak-feed-container-ajax").each(function(i,e){
          console.log(e);
          var $this = jQuery(this);
          var setting = $this.data("settings");

          var inveroak_feed_update_operators = function(atts) {
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                      atts: atts, 
                      action: "inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents"
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                      jQuery(".inveroak-feed-container-ajax").empty().append(data);
                      console.log("Operators updated");
                  }
              });
          }
          inveroak_feed_update_operators(setting);
          setInterval(inveroak_feed_update_operators.bind(null,setting), 30000);
        })
        });
        '
    );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_enqueue');

// The returned output of the AJAX shortcode
function inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents() {

    // Get the attributes from the posted AJAX call
    $atts = isset($_POST['atts']) ? $_POST['atts'] : null;

    // Echo the display feed function
    echo inveroak_feed_shortcode($_POST['atts']);
    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents', 'inveroak_feed_shortcode_ajax_contents');
```